# Código php para mostrar cadena de texto (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

En mi proyecto web he incrustado vídeos de Youtube, apareciendo al pie del vídeo el número de visualizaciones que tiene en Youtube, para ello, he incluido el siguiente código (ver apdo"**Código 2**"). Este código muestra el número de visualizaciones. Lo que necesito ahora  es aparezca la palabra *visualizaciones* junto al número. Lo he intentado definiendo una variable y, posteriormente, mostrando su contenido con la función `echo` o `print`,  pero no consigo que aparezca la palabra. Este es mi intento (ver apdo "**Código 1**"):

**Código 1:**

```
 $viewtext = "visualizaciones";
return number_format($views, 0, '', '.'); /*Para que aparezcan puntos en los miles */
print '$viewtext';
```

**Código 2**

```
function youtube_view_count_shortcode($params) {
 $videoID = $params['id'];
 $json = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=" . $videoID . "&key=AIzaSyAdIxrKb2xx7ylckO2uj3RShaKCP79Ipz0");
 $jsonData = json_decode($json);
 $views = $jsonData->items[0]->statistics->viewCount;
 $viewtext = "visualizaciones";
  return number_format($views, 0, '', '.'); /*Para que aparezcan puntos en los miles */
  print ('$viewtext');  
}
add_shortcode('youtube_view_count', 'youtube_view_count_shortcode');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que cuando haces "return" se sale de la función y no continua porque así lo entiende php y cree que ya ha terminado. Lo que necesitas hacer es guardar el string completo (x visualizaciones) y luego hacer return:

```
 $viewtext = "visualizaciones";
 $result = number_format($views, 0, '', '.');
 return $result . " " . $viewtext;
```

Comment: Gracias!!! Todo correcto. Saludos